Is it possible to use JavaScript in C#.net web app to read Mifare card at android NFC?
I use C#.Net to create web app on an Android device. Is it possible to read a Mifare card through NFC on an Android device with Javascript like this and handling NFC Events?
I want to read block 1 of Mifare and using factory default keys 0x FF FF FF FF FF FF
in aspx file:
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style59">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
  ...

<script src="jquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function NFCRead() {
        ...
    }
</script>

</asp:Content> 

I have tried other ways and still no success

It depends on the exact type of Mifare Tag and the data stored. Mifare Classic are non standard and might support the Ndef data format on some hardware. But the answer is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/79023232/2373819 in that Ndef data format on some NFC Tags can be read by a small set of hardware.

Thank you dear friend for your answer . there is a link to https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/mifare/jsdoc/overview-summary-mifare.js.html Code can i using it in my app

You have to call this function when you scan card.
function NFCRead() {
   try {
            const ndef = new NDEFReader();
            await ndef.scan();
            ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", () => {
                console.log("Argh! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?");
            });
            ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
                // convert Serial Hex to DEC
                let cleanSerialNumber = serialNumber.replace(/:/g, "");
                serialDecNumber = parseInt(cleanSerialNumber, 16);
                console.log('Serial Number: ' + serialDecNumber);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
}


I appreciate your answer

Are you sure that this method will read a sector or block on a Mifare Classic Tag ? This method seems to read a NDEF Message from a Tag and the data is stored in sectors or blocks on the tag but reading a Single Sektor seems not possible, sorry.

it is true It is not so easy to get information from mifare card,  of course I found these codes, but I don't know how to use them. https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/mifare/jsdoc/overview-summary-mifare.js.html

As you added detail that suggests that the Tag is a Mifare Classic Tag and you are wanting to read Block 1, then this is not using the Ndef Data format so the answer is No this is not possible with just Javascript.
Only possible with a Native App.

Thank you very much for your answer I found this link https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/mifare/jsdoc/overview-summary-mifare.js.html  how can i use it?
